# Regexp for adding a blank after each character of an String

Tags: java, regex

I'm looking for the way of replacing each char of a Java String for the character+ a blank (except the last one or removing the trailing blank at the end)

The idea is from `STACKOVERFLOW` return `S T A C K  O V E R F L O W`. Is possible to do this with a regexp or should I iterate the string?

Thanks

Comment: No need for a regex here.  Just loop over the chars in the String.  Both ways will work fine, but there is no reason to incur the extra overhead involved with using regexes.

Comment: what about whitespace already in the string? add another one there, too?

Comment: Is there any reason for wanting to use a regex instead of iterating?  Just wondering.

Comment: jlordo: the string do not have whitespaces. KLee: I'm just looking for the faster way of doing this

Comment: If you want speed, avoid using a regex and iterate.  If you don't care about speed and you want a one liner, use a regex.

Comment: @KLee1 - well at least just for the reason of having a nicer and cleaner code instead of having annoying long loop instead of just one line...

Comment: Put the loop in its own method. That way it's fast, it's not ugly _AND_ you can re-use it elsewhere. About to edit my answer...

Answer (score 10, accepted):

```
"StackOverFlow".replaceAll(".(?!$)", "$0 "));
```

Answer (score 2):

There's no need for a regex.

Just iterate over the String and use a StringBuilder:

```
String withSpaces = addSpaces("StackOverflow");
```

---

```
public String addSpaces(String s) {
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    for (int i = 0; i < s.length(); i++) {
        sb.append(s.charAt(i)).append(" ");
    }
    return sb.substring(0, sb.length() - 1);
}
```

Comment: i would call replaceAll(",$", "") at the end. to remove the trailing space

Comment: @chaitanya10 - Using _substring_ is better in this context.

Answer (score 2):

Go with

```
str.replaceAll("(?<!^)(?!$)", " ");
```

or equivalent

```
str.replaceAll("(?<=.)(?!$)", " ");
```

...or if you want to add space character just behind non-space character, then use

```
str.replaceAll("(?<=\S)(?!$)", " ");
```

...and if you want to prevent double spaces (in case some space is already there), then use

```
str.replaceAll("(?<=\S)(?!\s)(?!$)", " ");
```